# Delete value from serialized Array in ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, activerecord

I have a rails model set up as:

```
class Master < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :submasters
  serialize :subdocs, Array
end
```

It has a serialized `array` of `submaster_docs` which stores the `id` of the connected `subdocs` and my model for `Subdocs` is:

```
class Subdocs < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now I have a rails method which deletes a `subdoc` when user clicks on the delete button.

While deleting the Subdocs entries I want to remove the id of the `Subdocs` from `Master` also so that it doesn't try to create an association between them even after deleting `Subdocs`

My database entry of `Master` looks as follows:

```
<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Master id: 3, user_id: 1, name: "Being Batman", description: "Every man who has lotted here over the centuries, ...", subdocs: ["5"]>]>
```

Database entry of `subdoc`:

```
<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Subdoc id: 5, user_id: 1, name: "subdoc1.pdf">]>
```

Over here for example if a user deletes the subdoc 5 then I want to remove that value from `subdocs` array of all `Master`'s

My method for deleting the subdocs is as follows:

```
def destroy
  @masters = {}
  @subdoc = Subdoc.find(params[:id])
  @masters = current_user.user.masters

  # Tried these methods to delete the value.
  # @subdocs = @masters.select { |t| t.subdocs.to_a - [params[:id]] }
  # @subdocs = @masters.each { |t| t[:subdocs] - params[:id] }   

  @subdoc.destroy
  return render :status => 200, :json => { :success => true }    
end
```

But this throws me the error: `No Implicit conversion of String into Array`

How can I correct this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree with max and you should not use this architecture, assuming you keep it as is, you will need to delete the item from the array in master and save master.

```
def destroy
  @masters = {}
  @subdoc = Subdoc.find(params[:id])
  @masters = current_user.user.masters
  @masters.each do |master| 
    if master.subdocs.index(params[:id])
      master.subdocs.delete(params[:id])
      master.save!
    end
  end  

  @subdoc.destroy
  return render :status => 200, :json => { :success => true }    
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use an array here. Especially not a serialized array:

- You have to scan a string to be able use the column in a query.
- ActiveRecord associations are built to work with actual foreign key columns. So are relational databases.
- You get no referential integrity.

So start by creating a migration `rails g migration add_master_to_subdocs`

```
class AddMasterToSubdocs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :subdocs, :master, foreign_key: true
    remove_column :subdocs, :user_id
  end
end
```

We are also removing the `user_id` column since it won't be needed:

```
class Master < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :submasters
  has_many :subdocs
end

class Subdocs < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :master
  has_one :user, through: :master
end
```

Comment: If you want a Subdoc to belong to many Masters then use a join table and declare the association as [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

Comment: Although what you're saying makes logical sense but I'm working on a legacy application and I'm not allowed to make changes to the database. I need to use the existing table and models to do this :/

Comment: I guess my only advice then is to run away from the project as fast you can.